# SwiftUI - Invert a boolean binding

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `Binding<Bool>` binding in a swiftUI view. Something along the lines of:

```
struct MyCoolView: View { 
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View { 
        Text("Here is a cool Text!").sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.MyProperty) { 
            SomeModalView()}
        }
}
```

I want the `isPresented` to use the *opposite* boolean value of what is stored in the property using Boolean negation, the exclamation point `!` operator, or some other method.

Swift wont let me just do something like

```
.sheet(isPresented: !$viewModel.MyProperty)
```

`!$viewModel` gives the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'

Any thoughts on how to deal with this?

Comment: Could you just not invert it already in a the viewModel before it get sent to the view? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I should update and say that with about a year and a half of hindsight and a better sense of how to properly use Combine and publishers what you suggest is indeed the correct way to do it. The way I'd approach this now is to create a subscription to the Boolean inside the view model that is stored inside another published variable. I suppose time makes fools of us all on SO.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can build a binding by yourself:

```
Text("Here is a cool Text!").sheet(isPresented:
         Binding<Bool>(get: {return !self.viewModel.MyProperty},
                       set: { p in self.viewModel.MyProperty = p})
          { SomeModalView()} }
```

Comment: Small correction: add `!` in `set`. I.e., `self.viewModel.MyProperty = !p`.

Answer (score 64):

What about creating a custom prefix operator?

```
prefix func ! (value: Binding<Bool>) -> Binding<Bool> {
    Binding<Bool>(
        get: { !value.wrappedValue },
        set: { value.wrappedValue = !$0 }
    )
}
```

Then you could run your code without any modification:

```
.sheet(isPresented: !$viewModel.MyProperty)
```

If you don't like operators you could create an extension on Binding type:

```
extension Binding where Value == Bool {
    var not: Binding<Value> {
        Binding<Value>(
            get: { !self.wrappedValue },
            set: { self.wrappedValue = !$0 }
        )
    }
}
```

and later do something like:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.MyProperty.not)
```

or even experiment with a global not function:

```
func not(_ value: Binding<Bool>) -> Binding<Bool> {
    Binding<Bool>(
        get: { !value.wrappedValue },
        set: { value.wrappedValue = !$0 }
    )
}
```

and use it like that:

```
.sheet(isPresented: not($viewModel.MyProperty))
```

Comment: You mean `b in self.wrappedValue = !b`, right? Other than that nice answer :)

Comment: Actually, when I negate in setter and getter I will have the same result (without negation). So we should either negate in getter or setter not in two places. Probably negating in the setter is more straightforward though.

Comment: Nope, your code actually produces flipped results when you use the setter. If you input `true` to the setter, it will set the `value.wrappedValue` to `true` instead of setting the value of the negated binding to `true`. Try setting `returnedBinding.wrappedValue = true` where `returnedBinding` is the output of your `!anotherBinding` operator and you'll see that if you call `returnedBinding.wrappedValue` straight after, it will return `false` instead of `true`.

Comment: @tgebarowski very nice extensions and functions, but need a little fix. You should reverse the value on set, like
`set: { value.wrappedValue = !$0 }`

Comment: extension is perfect

Comment: The extension is such an elegant solution, thank you so much!

Comment: @tgebarowski go wrong if put prefix operate into swift package, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75808263/problem-using-prefix-operator-from-framework

Answer (score 10):

Based off @E.Com's answer, here is a shorter way to construct a `Binding<Bool>`:

```
Binding<Bool>(
    get: { !yourBindingBool },
    set: { yourBindingBool = !$0 }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Add extension like so:

```
extension Binding where Value == Bool {
    func negate() -> Bool {
        return !(self.wrappedValue)
    }
}
```