# Which prefix operator ! works, global or extension binding?

Tags: swiftui, binding, swift-package

I made a test code for inverted bool binding as following, including almost binding ways I can think of(except @Environment...).

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var isOn: Bool = false
    @State private var parameter: Parameter = .init()
    @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("isOff = \(isOn.description)", isOn: !$isOn)
            Toggle("isOff = \(parameter.isOn.description)", isOn: !$parameter.isOn)
            Toggle("isOff = \(vm.isOn.description)", isOn: !$vm.isOn)
            Toggle("isOff = \(vm.parameter.isOn.description)", isOn: !$vm.parameter.isOn)
            InnerView { isOn in
                Toggle("isOff = \(isOn.wrappedValue.description)", isOn: !isOn)
            } t2: { parameter in
                Toggle("isOff = \(parameter.wrappedValue.isOn.description)", isOn: !parameter.isOn)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    @MainActor
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var isOn: Bool = false
        @Published var parameter: Parameter = .init()
    }
    
    struct Parameter {
        var isOn: Bool = false
    }
    
    struct InnerView<T>: View where T: View {
        @State private var isOn: Bool = false
        @State private var parameter: Parameter = .init()
        @StateObject private var vm: ViewModel = .init()
        
        let t1: (Binding<Bool>) -> T
        let t2: (Binding<Parameter>) -> T
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                t1($isOn)
                t2($parameter)
                t1($vm.isOn)
                t1($vm.parameter.isOn)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Q1: here define the prefix operator ! in 2 ways: global and extension binding. which works? They don't conflict if put together, and if comment one and the other works fine.

```
prefix operator !

prefix func !(value: Binding<Bool>) -> Binding<Bool> {
    Binding<Bool>(
        get: { !value.wrappedValue },
        set: { value.wrappedValue = !$0 }
    )
}

extension Binding where Value == Bool {
    static prefix func !(value: Binding<Bool>) -> Binding<Bool> {
        Binding<Bool>(
        get: { !value.wrappedValue },
        set: { value.wrappedValue = !$0 }
    )
    }
}
```

if I comment the global one, and change extension one like following, strange things happened, compile success and run run crash.

```
//prefix operator !
//
//prefix func !(value: Binding<Bool>) -> Binding<Bool> {
//    Binding<Bool>(
//        get: { !value.wrappedValue },
//        set: { value.wrappedValue = !$0 }
//    )
//}

extension Binding where Value == Bool {
    static prefix func !(value: Binding<Bool>) -> Binding<Bool> {
        !value
    }
}
```

Q2: if I put the prefix operator ! definition into a Swift Package framework, some tests will compile failed as ['Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to expected argument type 'Bool'. Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75808263/problem-using-prefix-operator-from-framework). Is it a wrong way to define or some problems about Swift Package?

Q3: in 'Toggle("isOff = (vm.isOn.description)", isOn: !$vm.isOn)', $vm is a binding< ViewModel >, isON is Bool, is $vm.isON a binding< Bool >? I think it is. But if not, what's it? if not, the operator cannot be used on it, right? I'm kind of confused.

Comment: For me it makes more sense to define an operator in an extension to the type it operates on. In general I think it’s best to avoid global declarations if possible. And you don’t need to declare the `!` operator since it already exists.

Comment: But this global(and extension) with parameter Binding<Bool>. not the Bool which is already exist.

Comment: I was referring to the declaration `prefix operator !` only which isn’t needed.

Comment: we don't use view model objects in SwiftUI, that's not what StateObject is designed for